# Rails Bootstrap Devise Cancan Passenger Ubuntu deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

I've successfully installed Nginx and Passenger then made them run together to run Rails but I'm getting below error in my log

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Started GET "/" for 111.222.333.444 at 2013-08-07 19:44:43 +1000
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'users'):
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:3:in `index'
```

I've already run

```
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
```

I also tried

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production"
rake db:seed RAILS_ENV="production"
```

But I'm getting same error.

I've tried to look at Nginx configurations which was installed via `rvmsudo` but this seems to be ok. Also Passenger was installed using `gem` and Nginx is preloading Passenger hence why I'm getting the 500 error page from Rails.

What could be wrong?

```
http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.10;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  logs/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  rails_test.dev;

        passenger_enabled on;

        root /var/www/rails_test/public;
        charset utf-8;

        rails_env production;
}

passenger_pre_start http://rails_test.dev;
```

Comment: How did you install passenger and configure it to work with nginx? Can you please show your configuration from nginx for passenger?

Comment: updated with nginx conf. Passenger was installed with gem

Comment: Some shells don't like environment variables after the command. Try running `export RAILS_ENV=production`, then running `rake db:migrate`, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it but getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer! The issue was the write permission on tmp/cache folder!
I found this out by changing the Nginx `rails_env` value to `development`

Hope this helps people having similar issues with deployment!